# Does power consumption vary over time as a projectile travels down the barrel of a rail gun?

Tags: electromagnetism, acceleration

My assumptions (possibly incorrect) for a rail gun are that are that the mass of the projectile is constant, the current through the armature is constant, and the magnetic field strength along the barrel is constant. Therefore, according to Lorentz's law, the force on the projectile should be constant, and thus its acceleration should be constant. But if the acceleration is constant then the power consumption is not constant, according to Power(kg*m2/s3) = m(kg) * a(m/s2) * v(m/s). So, presumably, somehow, power consumption increases over time as a projectile travels down the barrel of a rail gun.

If this is correct, can someone explain the physics and math of how and why the power consumed by a rail gun varies with time?

Answer (score 0):

There is a back-emf caused by the motion of the projectile through the magnetic field (Faraday's Law of induction).  The back-emf is seen as a voltage across the driving terminals.  The voltage is proportional to the projectile velocity (ignoring ohmic and contact losses).

So, although the current may be relatively constant and held near some maximum value, the driving voltage will rapidly increase as will the power (current x voltage) that must be delivered. Designing the system to efficiently and safely deliver that power is quite a challenge.

Comment: Thanks! So I gather that ideally a constant acceleration system should be designed to increase the voltage across the armature linearly with time to compensate for the back-emf, which is a function of velocity and thus is also increasing linearly with time...?

Comment: @phil1008 Yes, ideally, but it's likely that losses to contact resistance and ohmic resistance are also significant